# Javascript redefine private function

Tags: javascript

Im tying to build a simple object similar to jQuery but I just cant figure out how to redefine a function inside the object.

How can I recreate a custom errorHandler outside of the ZOO object or am I going about this the wrong way; I read prototyping might be a better method, but then again, I only define the object once.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script>
        (function( $ ) {
            var hasError = 0;

            var errorHandler = function(msg) {
                hasError = 1;
                console.log('Before: ' + msg);
            };

            var callback = {
                success: function(data) { },
                failure: function(msg) { }
            };

            $.init = function() {
                try {
                    something_bad;
                }
                catch(e) {
                    errorHandler(e.toString());
                }
                callback.success(1);
            };

            $.override = function(methodName, method) {
                // How do i redefine the method??
                methodName = method;
            };

        }(window.ZOO = window.ZOO || {}));
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<script>
    ZOO.override('errorHandler', function(msg) {
        hasError = 1;
        console.log('After: ' + msg);
    });

    ZOO.override('callback.success', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });

    ZOO.init();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not simply make it a public `$.errorHandler` method if you want it to be overwritable? No need to use prototypes, just properties.

Comment: @Bergi Because then it wont get access to the private properties and methods so I would have to make them public too but I dont want some properties or methods accessible in public.

Comment: No, the original function still would have access to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The private function has the `this` context as `window`. There seems to be some internal function variable created and we can use the function name as a variable:

```
 $.override = function(methodName, method) {
     errorHandler = method;
 };
```

As suggested by T.J.Crowder, you should define a function variable like this:

```
var errorHandler = function(msg) { ... }
```

**Update:** To make it dynamic, you can use the `eval()` function like this:

```
$.override = function(methodName, method) {
     eval(methodName + " = method");
};
```

Comment: Quite so. In general, I recommend changing the original function creation to `var errorHandler = function...` if you're going to overwrite the value later, but there's no *requirement* to.

Comment: but that doesnt allow dynamic re-assignment. What if I had another method i wanted to override?

Comment: @Christian not sure what you meant, with that method you always call the `$.override` to override, then the assignment does change your `errorHandler`. That's all.

Comment: @King King, but what if i had a another method in side the object. I have altered the code to show an example

Comment: @Christian sorry, couldn't believe I missed that out. Please see my update for dynamic code.

Comment: I went with your original edit of `eval(methodName +"="+ method);`. The way Bergi suggested it set `errorHandler = method`

Comment: @Christian I've also tried that edited version and it does work. Looks like it's the better. However in this case the handler is your code so using my previous code is OK. There are some internal/native functions which can't be stringified correctly. That's when we should use the Bergi's code.

Comment: I've actually found that the following works the best `if (args[k].constructor == Function) eval(k + "=" + args[k]); else eval(k + "= args[k]");`. If I just use your method of quoting the method, it can be called but it doesn't have access to the private methods/properties

Answer (score 0):

I would choose protoryping:
Check [this fiddle is for you!](http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/81r4ktj4/)

Implementation:

```
function ZOOd (){ 
    this.hasError= 0;
} 

ZOOd.prototype.errorHandler = function(msg){ 
    this.hasError = 1;
    console.log('Before: ' + msg);
} 

ZOOd.prototype.init =function(){ 
    try {
        /*something_bad;*/
    }
    catch(e) {
        this.errorHandler(e.toString());
    }
} 



ZOO.prototype = new ZOOd();        // Here's where the inheritance occurs 
ZOO.prototype.constructor=ZOO;       // Otherwise instances of ZOO would have a constructor of ZOO 

function ZOO(){ 
    this.hasError= 0;
} 
ZOO.prototype.errorHandler = function(msg){ 
    this.hasError = 1;
    console.log('After: ' + msg);
} 

var zoo = new ZOO();
zoo.init();
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: That seems a little more complicated for the average Joe to implement. I'm writing a module for anyone, even those without coding skills trying to implement our product. `ZOO.override('errorHandler', function(msg) { console.log('After: ' + msg); });` Most people know what `override` means especially if they've watched a villain movie, so it seems more meaningful.

Comment: Yes maybe you have right but it was not so clear at the question.I tried to give the best way.It is your choice depend on your needs